# When i call view from other view in codigniter the page is not found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to submit my form using post method in codingniter , and my form is called from the main view  when i submit the form i get 404 Page is not found .

This is my header form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="sendform" role="form" action="<?php echo `base_url('/pages/insert_into_db') ;?>" method="post" >`
```

and in the controller i have this function controller :

pages.php :

```
        <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
public function view ($page='gurantee'){
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
      }  

    public function index ()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('Welome');
    }
     public function display () {

         $this->load->model('ektreemodel');
         $data['query']=$this->ektreemodel->display();
         $this->load->view('table',$data);
    }
      public function insert_to_db()
      {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('ektreemodel');
        $this->ektreemodel->insert_into_db();
        $this->load->view('gurantee');
    }

    public function dis () {
       $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('registration');
      }

}
```

and the url is :

```
http://localhost:8888/index.php/pages/index.php/pages/display
```

it was working fine when i submit my  form the main first view , 
is there something i have to change or , is there some way i can use javascript , so when i will use post method it will call display function from the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="sendform" role="form" action="<?php echo site_url('pages/display') ;?>" method="post" >`
```

Use this code that has `site_url()` rather than `base_url()`

**Solution 2**

If that doesn't work a more logical way would be:

```
echo form_open('pages/display', 'class="form-horizontal" id="sendform"');
```

This would generate the form tag for you. Hope this helps :)

**Solution #3:**

Make "p" capital in `pages.php` making it `Pages.php`

Comment: Still same page not found

Comment: i do not thing , base_url or site_url() will make any different

Comment: Please can you post the entire controller's code? Also did you try it with form_open() ?

Comment: i made small changes , in the call in the form but not big deal i just call the funcation insert_into_db()

Comment: Try solution #3 might help

Comment: solution 3 also is nor working , could please explain be more how i can solution 2 ! ?

Comment: Replace the entire <form> opening tag with the form_open() thing. Of course surround it with php tags. Load the form helper too. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="sendform" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'/pages/display' ;?>" method="post" >
```

To use base_url(), you must first have the URL Helper loaded.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Also make sure site's base url is provided in application/config/config.php.

Comment: i am using $this->load->helper('url');

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because i call view from another view i did not have to use base_ur since it will call localhost/index.php/controller.

i n my example i am in the place where my url is has been already call from the first view  .

So all what i need to do is change the form method post into :

" method="post" >

Where it will call directly : 
http://localhost:8888/index.php/pages/insert_to_db

where http://localhost:8888/index.php/pages/ it called already before , so need to call base_url from the start .